# Deleting Files which have a certain name

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

can someone steer me in the right direction.  I have 2GB worth of images, which include 3 types. Eg:

- thumb-12345.jpg
- popup-12345.jpg
- 12345.jpg

Is there a quick script/command I could run to remove all the files which do not have 'thumb' or 'popup' in the name. Basically - I just need to remove the '12345.jpg'

Quite new to this, any help would be appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*In all the snippets below, run the command to check if the files it displays are really the ones you want to delete. Then perform the deletion by replacing `echo` with `rm` or `-print` with `-delete`*

If all your files are in the same directory, you can remove the ones whose name starts with a digit.

```
echo [0-9]*.jpg
```

If your files live in a directory hierarchy, use `find`.

```
find . -name '[0-9]*.jpg' -print
```

If you specifically want to match `popup` and `thumb` and no other prefix:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' \( -name 'popup-*' -o -name 'thumb-*' -o -print \)
```

In bash ≥4.0 or zsh, there's a simpler way to traverse subdirectories, as long as you don't run into a command line length limitation. In bash, first run `shopt -s globstar`. Then:

```
echo **/[0-9]*.jpg
```

Comment: errr My snippets don't delete any data. I hate to bug you but I really really seldom give out something that deletes data without asking. (At least not unless someone really deserves that)

Comment: @ServerHorror Er, yes? We're on the same page then, my snippets don't delete data either.

Comment: You hit me on a sensitive topic with your first paragraph -- nothing to worry about :)

Answer (score 1):

Haha more than one way and less processes :)

Start by finding what you want to keep:

```
find -E . -type f -regex '.*((popup)|(thumb))-[[:digit:]]*\.jpg'
```

Negate the expression:

```
find -E . -type f \! -regex '.*((popup)|(thumb))-[[:digit:]]*\.jpg'
```

Works for your sample data....

If you're satisfied add a `-delete`.

Read up on it in [re_format(3)](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=re_format&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) and [find(1)](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) to know which options to apply so that your find understands *extended regular expressions*